# Return only matched multiValued field

Tags: solr

Assuming a multivalued, stored and indexed field with name `comment`.
When performing a search, I would like to return only the values of
`comment` which contain the match. For example:

When searching for "gold" instead of getting this result:

```
<doc>
    <arr name="comment">
        <str>Theres a lady whos sure</str>
        <str>all that glitters is gold</str>
        <str>and shes buying a stairway to heaven</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

I would prefer to get this result:

```
<doc>
    <arr name="comment">
        <str>all that glitters is gold</str>
    </arr>
</doc>
```

(psuedo-XML from memory, may not be accurate but illustrates the point)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried utilizing highlighting at all? That might be a workable approach.

Comment: Or maybe you write an xsl file and use it to ignore the lines you don´t want to be posted

Comment: The problem is that there are enough of these fields that moving them over the network from the Solr install to the client reading from Solr takes too long! The search is quick (~10ms) but downloading ~10 MB documents over the dialup network is problematic. Faster internet is not available at the client location. So I would prefer that Solr return only the matched fields, which should be on the order of kilobytes.

Comment: It looks like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3955 referred to in the accepted answer Is still OPEN.   Perhaps the only way to achieve this currently is by writing your own RequestHandler: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/SolrRequestHandler#SolrRequestHandler-ImplementingaRequestHandler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering conversations with other Solr users lead me to believe that this is a useful feature, I have filed a feature request:

[Solr: Return only matched multiValued field](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3955)