# Solr spatial search on multivalued location field

Tags: search, solr, geolocation

Is there a way in Solr to know the matching address within a document on a mutlivalued location field and not just the document. For example, i might have "Store A" with locations "100 Main Street, NY, 00001" and "100 NotMainStreet, NY, 00010" which are 40 miles apart. When I search for "00002" assuming "100 Main Street, NY, 00001" matches, I want result to somehow indicate location "100 Main Street, NY" of "Store A" matches.

I tried Solr2155 patch for Solr3.5 but I could not find anything in there that can achieve this, I checked out documentation of new Solr4 Spatial Search module but I dint find anything useful there as well. Please help, thank you

Comment: Seems like this is a known issue with any multi-valued field. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3955 (got that from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377718/return-only-matched-multivalued-field)