# How to filter values returned on a multivalued field in Solr

Tags: solr, solr4

I have a document with a field called uuids. This field is a list (multivalued) can have up to 100k values per document.

I want to search for documents that match uuids that start with "5ff6115e" for instance. I can already do it successfully by using `q=uuids:5ff6115e*`:

http://localhost:8983/solr/test1/select?q=uuids%3A5ff6115e*&rows=1&fl=uuids&wt=json&indent=true

However, the resultant document brings me all 100k values for this field.

What I want is not only filter the documents whose uuids field start with this value, but also filter the field values returned so that I will only receive specific values in the answer.

How to do that?

Comment: Duplicated question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/264907/retrieving-specific-fields-in-a-solr-query

Comment: It's a different question, as I don't want to filter just which fields will come in the result, but the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not currently possible; see [this bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3955) and [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12377718/return-only-matched-multivalued-field).

Answer (score 2):

Use highlighting.  @Jokin first mentioned it and I feel this is the best answer without hacking on Solr.  Try either the PostingsHighlighter or the FastVectorHighlighter, not the default/standard highlighter.  Unfortunately both of them internally execute a wildcard query against all UIDS in this field. FVH has the *opportunity* internally to be smarter about that but it's not implemented that way.

note: if it's within scope to write a little Java to add to Solr, the ideal answer would be to add term vectors (just the terms data in the term-vector, no offsets/positions) and then write a "DocTransformer" to grab the term vector terms; seek to the prefix, then iterate on those that have that prefix. Pretty darned fast.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how big it's your index, but having a document with 100k multivalued fields doesn't seem the right approach to me. In this cases instead of asking for a feature in solr, it's better to refactor your index and store the information in other way, maybe creating another core with documents that have each the uniqueid of your document and a field with the guid. You can use then field collapsing or other solr features to get the info that you need.

So, for example, a simple case in solr was to index books, and instead of indexing each book as a whole, it was better to index each separate page as a document. If you could tell us a bit more about your case we can think how the index can be improved.

Anyway, for cases that doesn't have so many values you can achive the same result with the highlighting component. for best performance you can exclude the field in the return field list, and use the highlighter to return the matched terms. You can tune the highlighter to get the maximum number of snippets and how big is each one etc. 
http://localhost:8893/solr/test1/select?q=uuids%3A5ff6115e*&rows=1&fl=id&wt=json&indent=true&hl=on&hl.fragsize=1&hl.fl=uuids

Comment: I don't agree it's not the right approach, it's how an inverted index is supposed to be used. When using solr, you must do everything you can to not make your model normalized. I want to store uuid_value in the list and then search for all values for the uuid, spread along several documents. This solution works fine for me, except for this solr limitation. It would be nice to store a map as well instead of a list, but I would still need to filter what comes in the result.

Comment: An inverted index it's suposed to have the information indexed the way that you are going to use it. There's no solr limitation, it's the way it works and how it's designed. for the index multivalued fields are just like a long string field with big slope between terms. You can use the highlighting component to return the matched content instead of the whole field, but take in account that solr will have to read the whole document field and make a  substr to get your info, so I still advise that you could come with another way to index your data.

Comment: The way it was designed was limited. I don't see a reason why Solr shouldn't support it. Storing the list as a long string field is probably an implementation detail, right? I might be missing knowledge here, but I don't see why this couldn't be indexed as well. Anyway, I understand your point and maybe it's a good thing to be asked in the mailing list, I will try to do it. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: what you want is an index inside an index, of course you could add more info but it would be a penalty with little or none benefit because what you want could be provided by other means. I updated the answer because event if it's not the best solution in your case that have so many values, with highlighting you can get what  you want.

Comment: This helped a lot. Using raw highlighting, the query gets too slow, so it's not an option (it was faster before the highlighting), but using hl.useFastVectorHighlighter=on it became fast enough, so it could solve my problem, although the result is not exactly what I wanted (I got "a5f5c3a4-c9e2-4a39-9791-721438eefb28_2870000 <em>12345_2870000</em>" as result but I was expecting just 12345_2870000). Anyway, it's a possible workaround.

Comment: I have also created another question about the model: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542735/best-solr-model-when-searching-inside-multivalued-fields