# Best Solr model when searching inside multivalued fields

Tags: solr, solr4

I have the following model for a type of document in Solr 5:

- 1 document per entity
- entity has about 100 single valued attributes
- entity has 1 multi valued attribute `uuids_scores`, which contains a value like "123_456", being the first part (123) the user id and the second part (456) a stored score I keep for each user.
- an entity can have about 100 k uuids_scores values.

The way I am trying to use this is:

I search for entities where `uuids_scores:123_*` and I get the list of entities I want.

Then I read in the answer all single attributes + the matched values inside `uuids_scores` multi valued field.

I found a way of doing it in this question: [How to filter values returned on a multivalued field in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29535197/how-to-filter-values-returned-on-a-multivalued-field-in-solr)

Considering as a requirement my writes should be as fast as possible, so any solution that would require storing 100k entities instead of one wouldn't work for me.

The question now is: is there a better model to do what I want? Is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with dynamic fields, index fields could be like "uuids_scores_123"

```
<dynamicField name="uuid_scores_*" type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true" multivalued="true"/>
```

you can query over "uuids_scores_123:*" and include only "uuids_scores_123" in returned fields. It will have only the results you want.

Comment: But would it be ok to have more than 100k fields in a document?

Comment: AFAIK, many values in a list is much better than many values in a document, in production, right?

Comment: not really, the field names are indexed so for me it's better to query with the exact field name that use a wildcard query in a field. But as many things in solr, you really should try both ways to compare which is better. for me this way is more flexible and having the scores stored as an int it's also a benefit(smaller size and memory footprint), facets, max - min functions.